# Printing number in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, cpu-registers

I'm currently working my way through learning writing my own programming language. Currently my language supports adding two numbers or subtracting and I want to now convert my AST into assembly. I'm running on a Linux machine in the x86_64 architecture and I've gone through the hello world tutorial with code that looks like:

```
section .data                                                                                                                                    
    string1 db  "Hello World!",10,0                                             
                                                                                 
section .text                                                                   
    global _start                                                               
    _start:                                                                     
        mov rax, 1                                                              
        mov rdi, 1                                                              
        mov rsi, string1                                                        
        mov rdx, 13                                                             
        syscall                                                                 
        mov rax, 60                                                             
        mov rdi, 0                                                              
        syscall
```

and I get what is happening here. Where I'm a little lost is in code like so:

```
section .text                                                                   
    global _start                                                               
    _start:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rbx, 2
        add rax, rbx
        mov rsi, rbx                                                                     
        mov rax, 1                                                              
        mov rdi, 1                                                        
        mov rdx, 1                                                             
        syscall                                                                 
        mov rax, 60                                                             
        mov rdi, 0                                                              
        syscall
```

As I understand what I've been reading, the above code should put the value `1` into the register `rax`, `2` into the register `rbx`, sum those registers and store it in `rbx`. Then, the value of `rbx` should be moved into `rsi` which should be the buffer argument for the `syscall` for write. Instead, nothing is printed to my console. If I put `"3"` in the `.data` section as a variable I can grab that and print it. So is it just the case that I cannot print an integer and it has to be stored in some data variable?

Comment: Is `write(1, (char*)3, 1)` a valid *pointer* to a buffer of data? (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html). No, it isn't.  `strace ./a.out` would show you that the system call returns `-EFAULT`.  It has to be in memory; it doesn't have to be in static storage.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact syntax of the syscalls, it seems to me that you would at least need to convert the result from the addition (3) into a string ("3", which is 51 is ASCII -- try adding 48 for single-digit numbers). A byte value of 3 does not encode a printable character, so the output will likely not show up in the console even if your call to the "print" routine is correct.

Comment: `write(1, (char*)3, 1)` is also not a valid pointer, so it's actually returning `-EFAULT`, not writing any bytes to stdout.